# How to start Chrome Hosted App in window?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

So I know that '**Chrome Packaged App**' will run in a window, I have tried to run the website I want in a `<webiview>` tag but it gets stuck at the beginning and I can't find a way to debug what's happenning inside that `<webview>` tag.

I now have tried to change the manifest to work as a '**Chrome Hosted App**' but it keeps opening in a tab.

How do I start my app in a window, either by having it as a chrome hosted app?

Or by `<webview>` (if I find a way to debug it)?

Comment: Typically, the user can choose to run hosted apps in a window by right clicking on their icon.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Chrome's built-in developer tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) can be used to debug packaged apps, extensions and webview as well as web pages (Right-click on any page element in webview and select Inspect Element).

Comment: yes but debugging javascript inside webview , I found a way is : adding event listener to webview , the event listener is : "consolemessage".

Comment: Yes, debugging javascript inside webview. Right-click on webview and select Inspect Element. You will see Chrome's built-in developer tools for webview. "consolemessage" have bugs. You will not be able to get all the information from the console.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed [here](http://www.omgchrome.com/new-hosted-app-frames-chrome-os/), a Chrome Hosted app can be open in a specific window if you enable this flag:

`Enables the web app style frame for hosted apps`

in `chrome://flags`.